# SSMA for Oracle: mapping long raw to image

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, migration

I need to migrate a database from Oracle to MsSql 2008. My problem is, that I need to map long raw from Oracle to Image in MsSql. Unfortunately when I want to change the mapping, there is no option on the combo box in ssma tool.

Is it possible to configure ssma to map long raw to image anyway?

P.S. I know that Image is a deprecated type but I can't use different one.

Comment: Long raw is also deprecated. It is unlikely that a migration tool will  support migration from a deprecated datatype to another deprecated datatype.

Comment: Since you're migrating the database, why not just use the correct data type in SQL Server, i.e. `varbinary(max)`? It sounds like you're creating a completely new SQL Server database, and if that's correct then I don't understand why you would have any restrictions?